# Translator Exercise by using string_view (c++)

Tags: c++

I have the following task

Develop a class called Translator that allows saving bilingual word pairs and then translating words from one language to another using the already added pairs:

```cpp
class Translator {
public:
  void Add(string_view source, string_view target);
  string_view TranslateForward(string_view source) const;
  string_view TranslateBackward(string_view target) const;;

private:
//
};
```

More specifically, an object `t` of type `Translator` should support the following actions:

1. Creation using the default constructor. In this case, the translation base is empty.
2. Adding a bilingual pair: `t.Add(source, target)`. After this call, it is assumed that the word `source` in language 1 corresponds to the word `target` in language 2. The strings passed to the `Add` method may be destroyed before the `t` object.
3. Translation from language 1 to language 2: `t.TranslateForward(source)`. If there was a previous call `t.Add(source_copy, target)` for some string `target` and a string `source_copy` equal to `source` (or being the same), it should return `target`. If there was no such call, it should return an empty string. If there were multiple such calls, it should return `target` for the last one.
4. Translation from language 2 to language 1: `t.TranslateBackward(target)`. If there was a previous call `t.Add(source, target_copy)` for some string `source` and a string `target_copy` equal to `target` (or being the same), it should return `source`. If there was no such call, it should return an empty string. If there were multiple such calls, it should return `source` for the last one.

Constraints:

- Each string should be stored in the `Translator` class instance no more than once. If this constraint is violated, you will receive a "Memory limit exceeded" error.

Basically I tried the following simple idea:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Translator {
public:
    void Add(string_view source, string_view target){
        forward[source] = target;
        backward[target] = source;
    };

    string_view TranslateForward(string_view source) const{
        if(forward.count(source) == 0){
            return string_view("");
        }
        return forward.at(source);
    };

    string_view TranslateBackward(string_view target) const{
        if(backward.count(target) == 0){
            return string_view("");
        }
        return backward.at(target);

    };

private:
    map<string_view,string_view> forward;
    map<string_view,string_view> backward;
};
```

I tested it with simple cases:

```
int main(){
    Translator translator;
    translator.Add(string("okno"), string("window"));
    translator.Add(string("stol"), string("table"));
}
```

And it works good. But on hidden test I got `TranslateForward() returned wrong data for temporary string (Time used: 1.78/5.00, preprocess time used: 0/None, memory used: 155656192/268435456.)`. It looks like I missed some edge cases.

What do I miss (in general as well)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key of the error is "temporary string". Why do you store string_views in the maps? Where is the actual string stored? What if the callers string ends its lifetime?

`std::string_view` is just a view. It does not own the data. It lets you view the data of some other object. If that other object ceases to exist you cannot view it anymore.

Even in your example, the actual string are temporaries that cease to exist after the full expression:

```
int main(){
    Translator translator;
    translator.Add(string("okno"), string("window"));
    translator.Add(string("stol"), string("table"));
    // already here the string_views in the map point to 
    // strings that no longer exist
}
```

Store strings in the map rather than views only.