# Correctly copying temporary string from a string_view (C++ 17)

Tags: c++, string, c++17

I have a function with the following declaration:

```
void Add(string_view source, string_view target);
```

What should it do: it adds a pair of words from string_views and saves them for the later usage:

- User types source word -> target word should be returned
- User types target word -> source word should be returned

I have a constraint, that I can have only 1 copy of each string. So my idea was to save string_views to maps (map<source string_view, target string_view> and the opposite) and these string_views should be views of the words, saved, for example in vector.

So the idea of `void Add(string_view source, string_view target)` is the following:

```
void Add(string_view source, string_view target){

 - save source string and target string to the vector<string> words;
 - create views from these words and save them into map<string_view source, string_view target>
 - create views from these words and save them into map<string_view target, string_view source>

}
```

From my previous post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78230725/translator-exercise-by-using-string-view-c/78230782#78230782][1] I understood, that strings (inserted into the function) are temporary and they got destroyed after they are out of their scope.

My question is: how can I save strings from the string_view (efficiently), such that I can later use string_views on them

**EDIT: Assignment**

Develop a class called Translator that allows saving bilingual word pairs and then translating words from one language to another using the already added pairs:

```cpp
class Translator {
public:
  void Add(string_view source, string_view target);
  string_view TranslateForward(string_view source) const;
  string_view TranslateBackward(string_view target) const;;

private:
//
};
```

More specifically, an object `t` of type `Translator` should support the following actions:

1. Creation using the default constructor. In this case, the translation base is empty.
2. Adding a bilingual pair: `t.Add(source, target)`. After this call, it is assumed that the word `source` in language 1 corresponds to the word `target` in language 2. The strings passed to the `Add` method may be destroyed before the `t` object.
3. Translation from language 1 to language 2: `t.TranslateForward(source)`. If there was a previous call `t.Add(source_copy, target)` for some string `target` and a string `source_copy` equal to `source` (or being the same), it should return `target`. If there was no such call, it should return an empty string. If there were multiple such calls, it should return `target` for the last one.
4. Translation from language 2 to language 1: `t.TranslateBackward(target)`. If there was a previous call `t.Add(source, target_copy)` for some string `source` and a string `target_copy` equal to `target` (or being the same), it should return `source`. If there was no such call, it should return an empty string. If there were multiple such calls, it should return `source` for the last one.

Constraints:

- Each string should be stored in the `Translator` class instance no more than once. If this constraint is violated, you will receive a "Memory limit exceeded" error.

**EDIT 2:** Just for the record, it's not the university assignment, but Online Course (if it's important).
[1]: [Translator Exercise by using string_view (c++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78230725/translator-exercise-by-using-string-view-c/78230782#78230782)

Comment: What is your underlying problem, exercise or assignment this `Add` function is supposed to solve? What are all your requirements and limitations?

Comment: As for `std::string_view`, it's really only a wrapper for a pointer to a *constant* string that is stored elsewhere. As it's constant, you really can't change it. It's also only a "view", so might not be the whole string, only part of it. If you need to modify a string, use `std::string` instead.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think this is a good idea to have a `vector<string>` and then have views on the strings stored in the vector.  If the vector is resized, then those `string_view`'s in the map will be pointing to invalid strings (assuming that the resizing exceeds the current vector capacity).

Comment: Store the strings in a separate structure. Map between them using some unique identifiers into that structure. (The requirements do not say that there can only be one copy in the entire program, only in the `Translator` class.)

Comment: To save strings from a string_view, you'll need to save the strings.  Which violates your constraint of not have additional copies of strings — especially since the *source* string is a temporary and the string_view will outlive the string.  That's quite a conundrum.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude requirements added to the post.

Comment: @Eljay I added description to the post about requirements.

Comment: Can you use the [boost](https://www.boost.org/) library?

Comment: @Caleth no, only standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the constraint carefully.

> Each string should be stored in the Translator class instance no more than once.

You can use `std::string` within `Translator`, and because the strings passed to `Add` might not outlive `t`, you must.

We'll use a vector of pairs, to hold each string only once. As the requirements don't specify complexity requirements, we can just linearly search in each direction.

```
class Translator {
public:
  void Add(string_view source, string_view target);
  string_view TranslateForward(string_view source) const;
  string_view TranslateBackward(string_view target) const;

private:
  void EraseIf(auto pred);
  auto MatchesSource(string_view source) const;
  auto MatchesTarget(string_view target) const;

  std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> translations;
  static const std::string empty;
};

const std::string Translator::empty;

void Translator::EraseIf(auto pred) 
{
    translations.erase(std::remove_if(translations.begin(), translations.end(), pred), translations.end());
}

auto Translator::MatchesSource(string_view source) const 
{ 
    return [source](auto & translation) { return translation.first == source; }; 
}

auto Translator::MatchesTarget(string_view target) const
{
    return [target](auto & translation) { return translation.second == target; }; 
}

void Translator::Add(string_view source, string_view target)
{
    // Ensure latest is the only translation by removing matches       
    EraseIf(MatchesSource(source));
    EraseIf(MatchesTarget(target));
    // Add the translation
    translations.emplace_back(source, target);
}

string_view Translator::TranslateForward(string_view source) const
{
    if (auto it = std::find_if(translations.begin(), translations.end(), MatchesSource(source)); it != translations.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    }
    return empty;
}

string_view Translator::TranslateBackward(string_view target) const
{
    if (auto it = std::find_if(translations.begin(), translations.end(), MatchesTarget(target)); it != translations.end())
    {
        return it->first;
    }
    return empty;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there any specific reason why are you using emplace_back instead of push_back?

Comment: @DaniilYefimov it constructs the value in place, rather than materialising a temporary and move-constructing the value.

Comment: I also experimented a little bit and tried to add source and target to the vector<string> (by using emplace_back) and for some reasons it throws me an error "unknown signal 6, stderr: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'", but for std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> (your variant) it works perfectly. Can you explain why please?

Comment: @DaniilYefimov There's no constructor for `std::string` that takes two `std::string_views`, how were you trying to emplace it? That sounds like you passes in two `char *`, which would use `std::string`'s range constructor. `vector<string>` is the wrong type to hold pairs of strings

Comment: I did it like that: all_strings.emplace_back(source); all_strings.emplace_back(target); where all_strings is std::vector<std::string>

Comment: The problem with `vector<string>` is that is you haven't associated the source with the target. Not sure why that has runtime errors